# Evaluating $a_j$ sum given the $n$-th partial sum. Not working.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate the sum $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$$ (or determine that it diverges) given the formula for its $n$-th partial sum $$S_n = \frac{n^2-4n+5}{n^3+7n-9}.$$

There are $2$ other $S_n$ given and both I am able to get the $a_j$ term by using $a_j = S_n - S_n-1$,
however when I attempted to get the $a_j$ for this $S_n$ I got a nasty looking poly that I can't seem to figure out what to do with. I tried to take the integral and the limit.

$$a_j=\left(\frac{n^2-4n+5}{n^3+7n-9}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(n-1\right)^2-4\left(n-1\right)+5}{\left(n-1\right)^3+7\left(n-1\right)-9}\right)=\frac{-n^4+10n^3-21n^2-6n+5}{\left(n^3+7n-9\right)\left(n^3-3n^2+10n-17\right)}.$$

Comment: $\sum a_j=\lim_{n} S_n=0  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum a_j$ is by definition just the limit of $S_n$ as $n \to \infty$. Dividing numerator and denominator by $n^{2}$ we can write $S_n$ as $\frac {1-4/n+5/n^{2}} {n+7/n-9/n^{2}}$ The numerator tends to $1$ and the denominator tends to $\infty$ and the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, definitely over complicated that. This makes sense I forgot you can just check the limit.